# Ошибка php Use of undefined constant

Tags: php

Ребят помогите пожалуйста ошибку выдает)))

Use of undefined constant object - assumed 'object'

вот собственно строка на которую ругается

public $parse = object;

Comment: Попробуйте `public $parse = 'object';`

Comment: неа, не работает

Comment: Что значит не работает? `$parse = stdClass();` либо `$parse = array();` - одно из двух

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что нет такого ключевого слова **object** в PHP. Интерпретатор рассматривает это как константу, но не находит и ее тоже. Тогда он решает что это вы просто забыли обернуть строку в кавычки и считает это строкой с содержимым 'object'. И предупреждает о том, что он сделал такое предположение.

Comment: Но тут дело такое что это все отлично работало в php 5.3 а вот в php 5.6 неработает